# Is my solution correct for this context free grammar?

Tags: grammar, context-free-grammar

I'm trying to solve this problem (I think I might have solved it): http://d.pr/i/L5Qm

> L = {a<sup>3n</sup>b<sup>2n</sup>  | n >= 0}

Basically the problem is saying `l` is not equal to `m` or `m` is not equal to `n`

**Rules that I've generated:**

```
S -> aaaSbb | A
A -> a | ^
```

**A few tests:**

```
Test one: S --> aaaSbb -> aaaAbb -> aaabb
Test two: S --> A -> a
Test three: S --> A -> ^
```

I'm sure there's a lot more that I could have tested but I'm not quite sure how to test for the majority of problems as I'm quite new to these. I'm thankful for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test two:

```
Test two: S --> A -> a
```

Clearly shows that your grammar is wrong!

In your language:

> L = {a<sup>3n</sup>b<sup>2n</sup>  | n >= 0}

You always have three **`a`** for each two **`b`**, and `a` is not in language L.

The correct productions for your language is:

```
S ---> aaaSbb | ^
```

Where `^` is null symbols. notice `^` is also in language because `n` can be `0`.

**Edit**:

you grammar:

```
S -> aaaSbb | A
A -> a | ^
```

produce union of two languages, that is:

> {a<sup>3n</sup>b<sup>2n</sup>  | n >= 0}  U  {a<sup>3n+1</sup>b<sup>2n</sup>  | n >= 0}

The extra part a<sup>3n+1</sup>b<sup>2n</sup> is due to `A--> a` production.